# Sacar el promedio de un Objeto con javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, mongodb

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llevo todo el día atorado con esto. Como se puede sacar un promedio de las evaluaciones.

La intención es mostrar un promedio por área por persona. considerando que hay muchas otras personas claro y hay que mostrarlas por cada uno.

Estoy manipulandolos con `node.js`, `handelbars` y `mongodeb`.

El resultado esperado seria algo como lo que se muestra en la imagen abajo, en cuanto al codigo esto fue lo mas lejos que llegue.

Tambien podria obtener un nuevo atributo del objeto athlete, llamado gralEvaluation... como se muestra al final

```
router.get('/athletes',isAuthenticated, async (req, res)=>{
    const athletes = await Athlete.find({user: req.user.id}).sort({date:'desc'});
    const teams = await Team.findById(athletes.team);
    var promediosMaterial = [];

    athletes.forEach(element => {
        evaluation = element.evaluations 

        console.log(evaluation)
        const evaluationsMaterial = []

        evaluation.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.material)
            evaluationsMaterial.push(parseInt(element.material));
        });
        promediosMaterial.push(evaluationsMaterial)
        console.log('promedio material',promediosMaterial);

        const sumaMaterial = evaluationsMaterial.reduce(function(a, b){return a + b});
        promedioMaterial = sumaMaterial / evaluationsMaterial.length
        console.log('promediio',promedioMaterial)
    }); 
    res.render('athletes/all-athletes',{athletes, teams});
});
```

```
{ personalInformation:
   [ { sexo: null,
       peso: '90',
       imc: '30',
       tallaPie: '170',
       tallaSentado: '70',
       FCbasal: '60',
       FCmaxima: '120',
       edadBiologica: '50',
       maduracion: 'estandar',
       date: 2019-09-04T00:38:19.805Z } ],
  _id: 5d6f0746702bbd5bdbcc4730,
  evaluations:
   [ { attendance: '2',
       material: '3',
       effort: '4',
       date: 2019-09-04T12:29:47.795Z },
     { attendance: '2',
       material: '2',
       effort: '5',
       date: 2019-09-04T12:31:20.220Z } ],
  gralEvaluation:
  [ { attendance: '2',
      material: '2.5,
      effort: '4.5' } ],
  nickName: 'cly',
  firstName: 'Claire',
  lastName: 'Keegan',
  gender: 'Mujer',
  team: '5d6ebe38b98d6e39f56a3684',
  born: '1968',
  date: 2019-09-04T00:37:26.672Z,
  user: '5d6ebde2b98d6e39f56a3683',
  __v: 3 }
```

Comment: puedes agregar el codigo que te da problemas

Comment: Hola, como te comenta @JackNavaRow, ¿qué has intentado? ¿cuál es la salida o respuesta esperada? ¿sobre qué campos vas a calcular promedios? ¿el documento de muestra es de una colección o es ya el resultado de una agregación? Faltan datos para poder responder a tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Pregunta actualizada, espero quede mas claro cual es la intención y me ayuden a resolver esto. Gracias totales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumo que la imagen del resultado esperado corresponde a la estructura actual de tu colección. Veo también que está usando Mongoose. Bueno, vamos a ver...

Tendrá que usar el marco de agregación para el resultado esperado(o el que pienso en realidad que espera obtener D:).

Entonces hacemos algo como esto:

```
router.get('/athletes', isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    const athletes = await Athlete.aggregate([
        {
            "$match":
            {
                // coincidencia con el campo "user"
                // normalmente es req.body.id
                // pero usted lo trabaja así 
                "user": req.user.id
            },

        },
        // me aseguro de mostrar todos los campos
        {
            "$project": {
                "personalInformation": "$personalInformation",
                '_id': '$_id',
                "evaluations": "$evaluations",
                // un extra aquí para mostrar todas las evaluaciones
                "evaluationsBack": "$evaluations",
                'nickName': '$nickName',
                'firstName': '$firstName',
                'lastName': '$lastName',
                'gender': '$gender',
                'team': '$team',
                'born': '$born',
                'date': '$date',
                'user': '$user',
            },
        },
        // desenrrollo "evaluations" para acceder a los materiales, y contar
        // cuantos hay
        {
            "$unwind":
            {
                "path": "$evaluations",
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
            }
        },
        // agrupo todo según el ID
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "personalInformation": { "$first": "$personalInformation" },
                // datos para el promedio //
                "averageMaterials": {
                    "$push": {
                        "material": "$evaluations.material",
                        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
                    }
                },
                // datos para el promedio //
                // campo "evaluations" //
                "evaluations": { "$first": "$evaluationsBack" },
                // campo "evaluations" //
                "nickName": { "$first": "$nickName" },
                "firstName": { "$first": "$firstName" },
                "lastName": { "$first": "$lastName" },
                "gender": { "$first": "$gender" },
                "team": { "$first": "$team" },
                "born": { "$first": "$born" },
                "date": { "$first": "$date" },
                "user": { "$first": "$user" },
            }
        },
        // desenrrollo los datos para el promedio
        {
            "$unwind":
            {
                "path": "$averageMaterials",
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
            }
        },
        // vuelvo a agrupar por el ID, pero esta vez
        // estoy sumando el campo "material" cada vez que se repita
        // lo mismo para el contador
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "personalInformation": { "$first": "$personalInformation" },
                // datos para el promedio //
                "material": { "$sum": "$averageMaterials.material" },
                "count": { "$sum": "$averageMaterials.count" },
                // datos para el promedio //
                "evaluations": { "$first": "$evaluations" },
                "nickName": { "$first": "$nickName" },
                "firstName": { "$first": "$firstName" },
                "lastName": { "$first": "$lastName" },
                "gender": { "$first": "$gender" },
                "team": { "$first": "$team" },
                "born": { "$first": "$born" },
                "date": { "$first": "$date" },
                "user": { "$first": "$user" },
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                '_id': '$_id',
                "personalInformation": "$personalInformation",
                "evaluations": "$evaluations",
                // el promedio, lo obtengo con el operador "$divide"
                // dividiendo el campo "materials" con la suma de los materiales
                // sobre la cantidad de los mismos
                "averageMaterials": { "$divide": ["$material", "$count"] },
                'nickName': '$nickName',
                'firstName': '$firstName',
                'lastName': '$lastName',
                'gender': '$gender',
                'team': '$team',
                'born': '$born',
                'date': '$date',
                'user': '$user',
            },
        },
        // y ahora lo ordenamos de forma descendente por fecha
        {
            "$sort": { "date": 1 }
        }
    ]);
    const teams = await Team.findById(athletes.team);
    res.render('athletes/all-athletes', { athletes, teams });
});
```

El resultado para la colección "Athletes" será, con la operación de agregación:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6f0746702bbd5bdbcc4730"),
    "personalInformation" : [ 
        {
            "sexo" : null,
            "peso" : "90",
            "imc" : "30",
            "tallaPie" : "170",
            "tallaSentado" : "70",
            "FCbasal" : "60",
            "FCmaxima" : "120",
            "edadBiologica" : "50",
            "maduracion" : "estandar",
            "date" : ISODate("2019-09-04T00:38:19.805Z")
        }
    ],
    "evaluations" : [ 
        {
            "attendance" : "2",
            "material" : 3,
            "effort" : "3",
            "date" : ISODate("2019-09-04T12:29:47.795Z")
        }, 
        {
            "attendance" : "2",
            "material" : 2,
            "effort" : "2",
            "date" : ISODate("2019-09-04T12:31:20.220Z")
        }
    ],
    // -- el promedio de materiales -- //
    "averageMaterials" : 2.5,
    "nickName" : "cly",
    "firstName" : "Claire",
    "lastName" : "Keegan",
    "gender" : "Mujer",
    "team" : "5d6ebe38b98d6e39f56a3684",
    "born" : "1968",
    "date" : ISODate("2019-09-04T00:37:26.672Z"),
    "user" : "5d6ebde2b98d6e39f56a3683"
}
```

**IMPORTANTE** POR FAVOR, convierta los campos "date" a formato de fecha, y el campo "materials" a numérico, o la agregación no funcionará(si en caso, claro está, no lo hizo aún).

En todo caso, debería empezar a guardarlos con los tipos de datos que corresponden.

Y me refiero a:

_id: como ObjectId.
date: como ISODate.
campos como materials, attendance, effort: como datos numéricos.

Es una recomendación para no tener problemas en el futuro y sus consultas sean menos tediosas de hacer.

Comment: Hola, primero muchas gracias, y perdon, por alguna razon no se pudo subir la imagen del resultado esperado, la tratare de añadir otra vez pero si no, seria algo asi en una tabla: 

apodo | material | esfuerzo | asistencia | genero | nombre 
 cly         3.5             4.5            4.0           mujer       Claire 

la intencion es mostrar este promedio, obteniendo el resultado de todas la evaluaciones realizadas a lo largo del tiempo. Cada vez se van añadiendo mas y mas evaluaciones.

Comment: por alguna extraña razón no puedo agregar imagenes

Comment: En todo caso, construya la estructura JSON que usted espera obtener y actualize su pregunta.

Comment: Pregunta editada nuevamente. espero ser mas claro. saludos

Comment: La respuesta fue mejor de lo que esperaba, la verdad me costo bastante tiempo entenderla (2 días) ya que soy nuevo sobre las consultas en mongodb. Gracias